# How to change user on a corporate Macbook?

Tags: macos, active-directory

So, I just got a Macbook @ work. Someone else had it before and when I start it I only see their name. I can't find any way of switching user. No place to enter username. The computer is connected to a large enterprise network.

Maybe it's locked to a single user through MDM and then I just have to wait for an OTA update?

How to switch user on an enterprise Macbook?

Comment: Please ask your system administrator. This question is about corporate IT and off topic here. Most likely there are no other accounts you can access.

Comment: Yes and no. [SF] is for system administrators and corporate IT, but your question is not really answerable. Simply ask your local IT and have them solve it.

Comment: @slhck why isn't it answerable? I could write a book on how to switch users in Windows, but I don't even know how to use copy and paste on a Mac.

Comment: It's not that it isn't answerable, it's that it involves corporate IT which is specifically off-topic here. The answer will include talking to your IT department to see what type of MDM they are using & asking them to change it for you. Bypassing corporate MDM is also off-topic. The inability to see or change other users is likely part of the MDM itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see that as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments - & to really just provide the 'why' as to this being not answerable on here…

It's not that it isn't answerable, it's that it involves corporate IT which is specifically off-topic here.

This is because any solution must come from them, so the answer will include talking to your IT department to see what type of MDM they are using & asking them to change it for you. Bypassing corporate MDM is also off-topic [otherwise this could be considered 'hacking'].
The inability to see or change other users is likely part of the MDM itself.

So really, the only answer there can ever be to this type of question is "Ask your IT department" as they are the only people who know what needs changing & have the authority to do it.

Comment: That's kind of a meta answer with an extended comment, not really solving the problem… IMO this belongs on [meta] or comments.

Comment: @slhck - yup, I'm aware. As a main Q it's off-topic, as a meta it's probably been covered before. I'm really only filling the 'check-box' as the OP requested. It would probably be better migrated then linked to the canonical, if there is one.

Comment: I don't see why a superuser can't use MDM? Ive been considering using it at home because I have a countless number of devices.

Comment: If it's ***your*** MDM then that wouldn't be an issue. I use an MDM solution here for my devices. It can be very useful. However, if it's a company one, then you would probably be breaking your company's IT policy trying to bypass it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I find that "can't be done because of MDM" is the correct answer. I couldn't find this anywhere on the internet.